# I have an issue with azure devops, I am given all the permissions to another user but still can not acces, the error is 401

Tags: azure-devops

[image: this is a screenshot of organization > settings]
[image: this is another from project settings > permissions]
`I give the user permissions at the organization level and project level, so idk what much to try. Still it given the 401 error message when the other user try to connect in the email invitation. I followed some tutorials and is how I done it. Pls some help :( it feels like it should be easy but is taking me too much time.`

Answer (score 0):

When the invited user clicks the email invitation, the browser automatically logs into the organization using the browser's previously cached default account, which may not be the invited account. Therefore a 401 error will be encountered.

You can try creating a new InPrivate window and in this InPrivate window, log in to the organization using the invited account: [https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BorganizationName%7D).

[image]